# sending e-mail with as3 without a dedicated server

Tags: actionscript-3

I need to have a button on my as3 i-pad app which sends an e-mail to myself with data the i-pad has collected.

The app is only for self use it wont be put into the i-store.

Is it possible to send such an e-mail without having a server?  Is it possible to do it with say a gmail account?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with the `Socket` class using [SMTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol). Try [SMTPMailer](http://www.bytearray.org/?p=27) for an implementation of this.

Be warned, though, that it's quite easy to mis-use SMTP. Your best option is to just use a dedicated mail server.

Comment: Thanks i decided to just go for a manual copy paste into my mailer option, less code :)